# Use AZURE BLOB to let user UPLOAD IMAGE (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, azure, api, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage

Asking for your input. I have created a project athrough ASP.NET - CRUD with EntityFramework

We have to use Azure services for deployment.

This is my setup:

1. Created Azure SQL database.
2. Completed the table for the data to be stored (name, age etc.)
3. Create ASP.NET API and scaffold. Success. Was able to view my data on the localhost.
4. Created AZURE web app service and publish my API. Checking the url its working so okay.
5. Completed ASP.NET MVC, called my deployed API app service. Modified controllers, models and views for my webform.
6. Created AZURE web app service and publish my MVC. So working CRUD, success retrieval of data.

So now working on uploading image.

How will I incorporate the uploading of image for my user(for ex those who will check my project) using blob. Do I need to add the step during my creation of API since I scaffold it? I'm now confused about how I can include my image retrieval from blob storage in my setup or workflow. I just able to work in my crud and still studying for image retrieval.

I have seen tutorials with regards to incorporating blob in asp.net. The problem is that they have only this image upload function in their example. My case is I do want to incorporate it with my CRUD.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Im sorry im new to coding and Im just 1 month in studying. Let me clarify the terms.

Comment: A good (imo) approach is to generate a short-lived SAS URI with write permission inside your server-side code somewhere (can be MVC project or your Web API project) and give that to the remote web-browser client, then use the browser's `fetch` API to make a `PUT` request to that SAS URI (with a JS `File` object (from an `<input type="file"/>`) as the request body - this will upload _directly_ to Azure Blob storage, then have the client send your service a notification that the upload completed which then triggers your own upload processing.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. I edit my post. You are right it is ASP.NET CORE MVC web app. So after publishin my API. I started working with my ASP.NET CORE MVC, I modified the needed code inside controllers and data annotation in my model. As well as the views. With this MVC, Im calling my API here that I published earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add the step during my creation of API since I scaffold it?

Asp.Net Core's scaffolding won't automatically help you integrate azure blob-related feature code.

If you want to use the relevant code in the auzre blob in the scaffolding, you need to combine the SDK or restapi to implement it yourself.